# Getting error when I load NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I am getting the following error when I tried to load NSCollectionviewItem in: `collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Error :

> could not instantiate an NSViewController for a nib in the
>   "CollectionViewCell" bundle because the bundle has not been loaded

I am loading CollectionViewItem from xib

Written following code in viewDidLoad

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
        self.collectionView.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

        if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {

            let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
            return item
        }

    return NSCollectionViewItem()
}
```

Comment: That's because item is not an object of CollectionViewCell.  Option-click on item.

Comment: Tried this also 
let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewItem (i.e my custom class of nscollectionviewitem)

Comment: Instantiate CollectionViewCell with item.

Comment: Done that also still getting error , if any demo available on git ?

Comment: Is `nib` nil? What's inside the nib?

Comment: No nib is not nil.Inside nib is a view loaded.

Comment: And a `NSCollectionViewItem`?